# How to create a one-line flex-box only using html

Tags: html, css, flexbox, content-management-system, inline

do you know if there is a way to create a responsive flex box layout with five boxes (without using a css-file)? I can currently only use inline css in the content system.

I've searched online and tried to find the right code but it didnt work.

Comment: HTML can't do CSS's job, CSS is made for styling. HTML is just a plain markup language.

Comment: I think your question is not quite clear. If you can't, for some reason, use CSS files you can always use CSS in an HTML file, either by inserting the CSS in the tag itself like <div style="display: flex;">...items</div> or by writing CSS the same way you would do in a CSS file but by opening styles tags like <style>...CSS</style>.

Anyway your question is vague, and as said only with pure HTML you cannot achieve a responsive flex layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,
As you see using inline css you can create a flex box layout

```html
<div class="flex-container" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div style="width: 20%; padding: 10px;">Box 1</div>
  <div style="width: 20%; padding: 10px;">Box 2</div>
  <div style="width: 20%; padding: 10px;">Box 3</div>
  <div style="width: 20%; padding: 10px;">Box 4</div>
  <div style="width: 20%; padding: 10px;">Box 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox the same way you do in normal CSS
You can add justify-content and align-items properties on "flex-container"
and flex-grow flex-shrink flex-grow properties on "flex-items"

```html
<div style="margin-top:100px; display:flex;">
  <div style="flex:1;">Home</div>
  <div style="flex:1;">Company</div>
  <div style="flex:1;">Services</div>
  <div style="flex:1;">About Us</div>
  <div style="flex:1;">Contact Us</div>
</div>
```